# Missing ':' in angular factory causing IE to crash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have a factory in Angular that I use to output certain messages to the console, but in IE I am getting a critical error

`JavaScript critical error at line 1700, column 9 in http://localhost:61246/Scripts/CustomScripts/app.js\n\nSCRIPT1003: Expected ':'`

Where line 1700 column 9 is the comma `, Info` I pass the constants back to the controllers, but I don't understand why IE is expecting a colon.

```
app.factory("ToConsole", ["$http", "$log", function ($http, $log) {
    const Info = 0;
    const Warning = 1;
    const Error = 2;
    const Debug = 3;
    const Alarm = 4;

    return {
        log: function (Description, Type) {
            switch (Type) {
                case 0:
                    $log.info(Description);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $log.warn(Description);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $log.error(Description);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $log.debug(Description);
                    break;
                default:
                    $log.info(Description);
                    break;
            }
        }
        , Info
        , Warning
        , Error
        , Debug
        , Alarm
    }
}]);
```

Comment: It doesn't support object shorthand property syntax?

Comment: You had incorrect object format, you need to have in key value pair like `Info: Info, Debug: Debug`

Comment: From what I can tell, you're returning an object, and not putting any information into the value of the key value pair. It expects it to be Info: "some info" (not necessarily a string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pankaj was right

```
, Info: Info
, Warning: Warning
, Error: Error
, Debug: Debug
, Alarm: Alarm
```

Fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is because your objects as listed is not in the key value pair format. Is there a reason you have created these consts?

I think you can put them into an array and access them by index instead of passing them as a key value pair.

```
var messages = ["Info", "Warning", "Error", "Debug", "Alarm"];
```